# Excel Finding or Highlighing Duplicates with 2 columns as basis

Tags: excel, sorting, duplicates

I am not sure if there is an existing question like this one. I will remove this post if there is any.

For example (I manually highlighted the duplicates in yellow using an image editor)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFqkJ.jpg

In the list, I only want to highlight if the date and the code beside it are duplicated on the next/consecutive row.
I can sort the list based on the dates, however, I do not want to highlight it if the codes are not of the same date as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select area to format -> Home Tab -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Your formula should then be `=AND($A1=$A2, $B1=$B2)` where:

- `$A:$A` and `$B:$B` are the columns you want to check in
- `$A1` and `$B1` are the values to be checked if they duplicate *in the first row of the selected range* (the range the conditional formatting will be applied to).

Then just edit the format (below the formula box) to however you want those cells to show up - I'm guessing set 'fill' to yellow.

If this finds a duplicate (2 rows that match) it will highlight the upper of those rows.

Comment: Sorry for the generic answer, a problem with my machine prevents me from viewing the imgur image, so you'll have to just adapt it a bit to suit your specific application

Comment: @spencerthank you so much. that did the trick! i am now trying to compare with 3 columns as bases but I guess it is already not in scope of the question... 
but thanks again!

Comment: @steveschmuck That's no problem, just add another column within the `And` function so it becomes `=AND($A1=$A2, $B1=$B2, $C2=$C2)` - and so on for any more columns you want to compare

Comment: if it works for you, please mark this answer as accepted so the question doesn't show as still unanswered to the rest of the StackOverflow community - click the tick on the left.